# Unable to access RabbitMQ details in Docker installed rabbitmq:3.7.8-managment

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I've read through tons of docs about connection failures. I have pretty much the same issue as most others, but solutions I've seen are usually around mismatched cookies. I have (and only need) 1 instance of RabbitMQ running on a server. I'm not trying to synchronize servers. Any suggestions welcome.

TYIA.

I have pulled down and installed the image form endpoint below.

This is on a RHEL Linux OS with Docker version 1.13.1.

https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/rabbitmq/3.7.8-management/images/sha256-d69a5113ceae5e68ab483f780c1ad712c3932a35753f69e6462b32a9f320ad9c?context=explore

I can start this using docker-compose and process seems fine. I've exposed the endpoints, but external wget or curl commands for the management stuff fails too.

```
rabbitmq     case.artifacts.medtronic.com/teneo-docker-dev-virtual/rabbitmq:3.7.8-management   
4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5671-5672->5671-5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp
```

Inside my container (docker exec -it) I can see the processes running.

```
root@e9df947eb6f5:/# ps aux
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
31309         1  0.0  0.0   4280   604 ?        Ss   20:12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
31309       207  0.0  0.0  30668   476 ?        S    20:12   0:00 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.3.3.3/bin/epmd -daemon
31309       493  0.4  1.0 2719932 80588 ?       Sl   20:12   0:22 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-9.3.3.3/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -MBas ageffcbf -MHas ageffcbf -MBlmbcs 512 -MHlmbcs 512 -MMmcs 30 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -
31309       601  0.0  0.0   4176   536 ?        Ss   20:12   0:01 erl_child_setup 1048576
31309       642  0.0  0.0  11416   356 ?        Ss   20:12   0:00 inet_gethost 4
31309       643  0.0  0.0  13536   448 ?        S    20:12   0:00 inet_gethost 4
root       5401  1.0  0.0  19964  2140 ?        Ss   21:46   0:00 bash
root       5410  0.0  0.0  38376  1748 ?        R+   21:46   0:00 ps aux
```

However, when I shell in to the container and run command rabbitmqctl status, I get errors.

```
root@e9df947eb6f5:/# rabbitmq status
bash: rabbitmq: command not found
root@e9df947eb6f5:/# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@e9df947eb6f5 ...
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@e9df947eb6f5'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on http://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@e9df947eb6f5

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@e9df947eb6f5]

rabbit@e9df947eb6f5:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on e9df947eb6f5
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Remote host closed TCP connection before completing authentication. Is the Erlang distribution using TLS?


Current node details:
 * node name: rabbitmqcli45@e9df947eb6f5
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: 3huACjSCtZSowuoZ0cY8jw==
```